# Business app made in Unity

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine

Have freelance job on VR - Business app and need to make it in VR and noVR modes.
Can I develop it in Unity and what problems can I face? Or can I make noVR-part in Android studio and then combine it with Unity VR-part?
Searching on the internet and can't find a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity 4.6+ has a new UI thats canvas based, its pretty ok but not as nice as a modern MVVM enabled UI frameworks. There are assets you can buy that enable MVVM in Unity UI. I would recommend this if your UI is complex

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/page=1/sortby=rating/query=mvvm

Answer (score -2):

The big problem with using Unity for any kind of business app type thing is that when entering text into GUI.TextFields you can't edit the text directly in the textbox. For any kind of form that has a bunch of textboxes and things to interact with, you need to do it in UIKit.I myself wouldnt use unity for what you want to do,  try to look into the google Android SDK.

Comment: *`you can't edit text in a textbox`* What? Yes you can. Unless there's something you *didn't say* that makes that make sense.